# How to avoid limesurvey to send a "survey completed" mail?

Tags: limesurvey

We have some surverys on which we don't want to send a mail to the user after he finished the survey. Is that possbile?

My only solution was to make all email templates empty. That blocked limesurvey from sending mails. Another solution would be to misconfigure the system so a mail can never be sent.

But both solutions are not satisfying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest LimeSurvey 2.0 there is a new survey setting where you can enable/disable the confirmation email.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just updated my installation and found the option. But the new version ... GREEN! ;)

Comment: You can change to the old admin appearance in the global settings (blobblueish) :-).